# Link to user account from active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to create a link from active admin to my user edit page.  I searched online here, but couldn't find anything that referenced creating links for specific users.  I'm guessing I'd add some code to the admin_user.rb page, but just unclear what I would need to add.  Also, would the active admin need permissions in order to get into a user's edit page, since this page is behind username and password?  Any help would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can add these lines in **config/initializers/active_admin.rb**:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.namespace :activeadmin do |admin|

    admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|

      user_menu = menu.add  label: proc { current_admin_user.email },
                              url: proc { edit_activeadmin_admin_user_url(current_active_admin_user.id) },
                               id: 'current_user',
                               if:  proc { current_active_admin_user } # Check the permissions here
      admin.add_logout_button_to_menu user_menu, 100
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks romaitnsalles.  I added that code and don't see any changes in my program.

Comment: Have you restarted your server? Have you clicked on your email at the top right corner?

Comment: With this code, when you click on the email address in the top right corner, you'll be redirected to the edit page of your current admin user. Wasn't it what you needed? If not, could you precise your need?

Comment: Thanks Romainsalles!  That's not what I'm looking for, sorry if I wasn't clear the first time.  Let me try to clarify.  What I'm looking for is a link from activeadmin to my application.  I'd like to be able to go into my user edit page from in the application, from active admin, which means I'd leave activeadim all together.  Does that make sense?